# How can I exclude a chapter from part in hyperref bookmarks?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, bookmarks, parts

I'm including my chapters in this way:

```
    \documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{Chapters/abstract}
\mainmatter 

\include{Chapters/Introduction}


\part{part1}
\include{Chapters/A}
\include{Chapters/B}
\include{Chapters/C}

\part{part2}
\include{Chapters/D}

\part{part3}
\include{Chapters/E}

\include{Chapters/Conclusions}

\cleardoublepage


\begin{appendices}
\include{Appendices/AppendixA}
\include{Appendices/AppendixB}
\end{appendices}


\backmatter
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

I want exclude the chapter `Conclusions`  from any part, like for the introduction. I don't want put the conclusion inside the part3, I want see it inside the index like a chapter without any part.
Is there a way to do that?

EDIT

now the ToC is:

```
Introduction

Part1
A
B
C

Part2
D

Part3
E
Conclusion
```

But I want:

```
Part1
A
B
C

Part2
D

Part3
E

(NO PART, like introduction)
Conclusion
```

EDIT 2:
[image]

I don't want that all those chapters are inside the Experiment section.

Comment: What should the resulting appearance be?  Would it be possible to put it in a part called `Epilogue` or some such, or after `\appendix`.  Does your documentclass have `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`?

Comment: I would go with the idea of Epilogue by @AndrewSwann - also consider Epigraph and the traditional parts of a book, e.g. https://www.thebookdesigner.com/2009/09/parts-of-a-book/ can help.

Comment: Please tell us what documentclass you are using so we know how parts are displayed and how chapters are numbered relative to parts.

Comment: What do you mean with *index*? Is it the table of contents or a real index or the PDF bookmarks? Can you please show a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of a code snippet and show or describe in detail the difference you want?

Comment: I still do not understand the wanted result. How does in the table of contents chapters in parts differ from chapters outside parts? Maybe you should just add a `\part{Appendix}` or `\part{Epilogue}` or just a `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{\baselineskip}}`. Don't know, what you want. And if you mean the table of contents please ask for the table of contents and not for the index.

Comment: One can relatively easily add more vertical space to the table of contents so this chapter is separated off by the space before a part entry, but visually this not very clear for the reader.

Comment: MWE means also *working* – cannot actually work with includes ;)
and there is no toc in that.

Comment: chapter entries in the table of contents are already separated by vertical space (`\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@`). As Andew already told, making more space is not very clear for the reader. Nevertheless, you can use `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{2.25em plus 1pt}}` (this is the extra vertical space of a part entry).

Comment: You have destroyed my correction of the description. Why? Does the new picture show the PDF bookmarks? So maybe is would be a `hyperref` question. But your example does neither have PDF bookmarks nor use `hyperref`. Please make a MWE (see link in den comment above). You can use package [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) to reset the bookmark levels.

Comment: @Teo: Those `\input/include` stuff is annoying and not useful for people willing to help you. You should not confuse people with `ToC` while your are meaning the `bookmarks` or `Document Outline`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add vertical space in the table contents corresponding to that added by the `\part` command via

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{2.25em}}
```

May be this is sufficient for your needs.  To manipulate the `hyperref` bookmarks you need to work a bit more.  This is included in the code below and gives

[image: Sample output]

with bookmarks

[image: Sample bookmarks]

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Chapters/abstract}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapters/Introduction}


\part{part1}
\chapter{Chapters/A}
\chapter{Chapters/B}
\chapter{Chapters/C}

\part{part2}
\chapter{Chapters/D}

\part{part3}
\chapter{Chapters/E}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{2.25em}}
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\chapter{Chapters/Conclusions}

\cleardoublepage

\pdfbookmark[-1]{Appendices}{appendix}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendices/AppendixA}
\chapter{Appendices/AppendixB}

\end{document}
```

To explain the bookmark changes, by default parts are at level `-1` and chapters at level `0`.  The `bookmark` package provides a the `startatroot` option to move the next entry up to the root (in this case `-1`) level.  (Thanks to Schweinebacke for pointing to me to this package that replaces my previous low level manipulations.)

I have also add a part like entry for the appendices via

```
\pdfbookmark[-1]{Appendices}{appendix}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if simply add a vertical space, inside the real toc the conclusion chapter is inside the experiments part. I added an image, maybe is more clear

Comment: Why not using excellent package `bookmark` (link in the question comments) to reset the bookmark level instead of manipulating internal commands of `hyperref`?

Comment: @Schweinebacke because I didn't know about that package, correct name is `bookmark`.  I'll update my answer.